# como desactivar o eliminar animaciones en app android, java.?

Tags: java, android, animación

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación para mi trabajo, solo que hay ciertas animaciones que realiza la app al cambiar de actividad que hacen que ciertos procesos sean un poco tediosos o lentos para el smartphone

Como podría desactivar las animaciones ocurridas en la app?(ya sea de cambio de actividad o de cualquier tipo).
me gustaría que fuera lo mas seco posible(no se si me pueda dar a entender).

Para mas detalle:
El plan es que pueda desactivar animaciones como en "modo programador" de android, pero solo para la app.

Desde mi main activity inicia asi:

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

y pues el mismo ejemplo con las siguientes activity

Aca mas completito el codigo:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
   final static String tag = "Main Activity";
   DatabaseHandler dbh;
   private ListView prodListView;
   String sname,scode,subic,sdate,salert,sid;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Action bar--------------------------
    ActionBar act = getSupportActionBar();
    act.hide();
    //------------------------------------


    prodListView = findViewById(R.id.mainslist);
    dbh = new DatabaseHandler(this);
    final Button btn_options = findViewById(R.id.btnSettings);
    final Button btn_products = findViewById(R.id.btnProducts);
    final Button btn_search = findViewById(R.id.btnBusqueda);
    filllistview();
    setToday();
```

El caso es que si yo inicio otra actividad hace una animacion muy basica donde la otra activity se sobrepone a la anterior, exactamente eso es lo que no quiero que pase.

esta es la forma en la que llamo una activity:

```
  btn_products.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View view) {
              Intent prod = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Productos.class);
            startActivity(prod);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Tendrias que poner codigo de la app por ejemplo donde realizas el pase entre activity's en esa parte en el onCreate tendrias por ejemplo un R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out y esa seria la transicion a sacar, pero sin condigo es imposible guiarte

Comment: No he agregado ningun tipo de animacion, solo lo hace automaticamente, en OnCreate solo tengo eso. pero nada de R.anim

Comment: Tus imagenes estan optimizadas, que realiza tu Activity principal? @KevinMora

Comment: Tu pregunta es como desactivar las transiciones, si tu app esta lenta, se mas especifico con tu pregunta @KevinMora

Comment: No hay que dar -1  Gilberto, mejor ayudar a @KevinMora a mejorar su pregunta.

Comment: lo que realiza la actividad principal es tomar una pequeña lista de una base de datos, el problema es al iniciar otras actividades, el dispositivo es de gama baja y consume recursos innecesarios ya que las otras actividades realizan operaciones un poco mas fuertes.

Comment: @KevinMora te recomiendo implementar fragments, eso podrá ayudarte a no tener todas las actividades al mismo tiempo, saludos!

Comment: @KevinMora La solucion no es eliminar las transiciones. la solucion es simplemente hacer el trabajo pesado en background y tener un dialogo que diga cargando .  Se que estas aprendiendo. simplemente toma el tiempo con unos breackpoints para ver que es lo que tarda en cargar.

Comment: :-/ ¿Como sabes que el problema se debe exclusivamente a "Lo que tiene mal es hacer mucho trabajo en el hilo principal" y como determinas que tiene una base de datos?. Es lo que te comentaba, ¿porque agregar una respuesta donde solo menciona como quitar las transiciones? como te había comentado inicialmente las transiciones no provocan que la aplicación sea lenta. :-)

Comment: @Jorgesys  Se le llama experiencia el saber por que una app esta lenta, y dije que era lo mas probable. . y este solo fue un comentario. Tu respuesta no tenia nada que ver con su pregunta, a lo que solo copiaste y pegaste en la tuya despues de mirar tu error. no es un foro de discucion.

Comment: Lo siento en realidad no tengo mucha experiencia :-( pero ayude a Kevin a solucionar el problema explicando primeramente que esa no es la causa del problema agregando una posible solución y agregando como plus como deshabilitar las animaciones que es lo que preguntaba:-).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En realidad las animaciones no deben ser un problema, cada sistema operativo muestra animaciones al realizar transiciones entre Actividades, comentas que tu aplicación se muestra "lenta", en realidad esto debe ser debido a otro problema.

De acuerdo a lo que comentas me parece que estas abriendo varias Activity, lo que puede provocar un alto consumo de memoria y por consiguiente "lentitud".

Te sugiero uses el método `finish()` para terminar la `Activity` que iniciara una nueva `Activity` y esta libere recursos.

```
btn_products.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View view) {
              Intent prod = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Productos.class);
              startActivity(prod);

              finish();
        }
    });
```

### Desactivar animaciones entre transiciones de Activity.

Si lo que deseas es desactivar las animaciones puedes usar el Flag:

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
```

Ejemplo:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Productos.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
overridePendingTransition(0,0);
```

Comment: @GilbertoIbarra las animaciones de transición no provocan que la aplicación sea lenta.

Comment: justo a eso me referia :) muchisimas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Para desactivar la animacion al iniciar actividad:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(activity, UserSearchActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
activity.startActivity(intent);
```

Y :

```
activity.overridePendingTransition(0, 0)
```